# error code:ORA-24344 from oracle's trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image]

I have an error, but I don't know why. I can't find a reason from oracle sql script. I need help.

Comment: You need to post this code as text.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Get rid of the `declares`. See the examples in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS20041

Answer (score 1):

1) You should use only one "decalre". Please preserve only first and delete all other
2) add ";" to the end of the script